# Can't launch flutter app on my iphone because of flutter_ios_build_temp_dirZZL8EG/temporary_xcresult_bundle?

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have an app that I can run on my PC, but when I try to run on my mac with the same code I have this error who stop running.

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-07-03 23:09:28.039 xcodebuild[54309:270223]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008030-000448183438802E was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f957ae1c710>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f957a9fcf80>{number = 6, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    2022-07-03 23:09:28.311 xcodebuild[54309:270230]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008030-000448183438802E was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f957ae1c710>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9579005b50>{number = 3, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    2022-07-03 23:09:28.406 xcodebuild[54309:270230]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008030-000448183438802E was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f957ae1c710>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9579005b50>{number = 3, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/19/zvrhzg415_b51k3jvc_vz1mr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.L5V1RD/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirZZL8EG/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/percent_indicator-4.2.1/lib/linear_percent_indicator.dart:162:5: Warning: The class 'WidgetsBinding' cannot be null.
    Try replacing '?.' with '.'
        WidgetsBinding?.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/percent_indicator-4.2.1/lib/linear_percent_indicator.dart:162:30: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
     - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    Try calling using ?. instead.
        WidgetsBinding?.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Failed to package /Users/XXXXX/AndroidStudioProjects/XXXX.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/19/zvrhzg415_b51k3jvc_vz1mr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.L5V1RD/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirZZL8EG/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
```

After flutter pub cache clean I have some new issues

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/19/zvrhzg415_b51k3jvc_vz1mr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.lzkxYb/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir6KlO8j/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Users/quentinguichot/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sensors_plus-1.3.2/ios/Classes/FLTSensorsPlusPlugin.m:45:24: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void _initMotionManager() {
                           ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/quentinguichot/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sensors_plus-1.3.2/ios/Classes/FLTSensorsPlusPlugin.m:45:24: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void _initMotionManager() {
                           ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/local/leveldb_index_manager.cc:43:
    /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/util/set_util.h:36:11: warning: parameter 'before' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     * @param before - The elements that exist in the original set.
              ^~~~~~
    /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/util/set_util.h:37:11: warning: parameter 'after' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     * @param after - The elements to diff against the original set.
              ^~~~~
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Source/API/FIRFirestore.mm:343:20: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        max_attempts = options.maxAttempts;
                     ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/local/leveldb_index_manager.cc:43:
    /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/util/set_util.h:36:11: warning: parameter 'before' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     * @param before - The elements that exist in the original set.
              ^~~~~~
    /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/util/set_util.h:37:11: warning: parameter 'after' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     * @param after - The elements to diff against the original set.
              ^~~~~
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Source/API/FIRFirestore.mm:343:20: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        max_attempts = options.maxAttempts;
                     ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/local/leveldb_index_manager.cc:43:
    /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/util/set_util.h:36:11: warning: parameter 'before' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     * @param before - The elements that exist in the original set.
              ^~~~~~
    /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/util/set_util.h:37:11: warning: parameter 'after' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     * @param after - The elements to diff against the original set.
              ^~~~~
    2 warnings generated.
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/percent_indicator-4.2.1/lib/linear_percent_indicator.dart:162:5: Warning: The class 'WidgetsBinding' cannot be null.
    Try replacing '?.' with '.'
        WidgetsBinding?.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/percent_indicator-4.2.1/lib/linear_percent_indicator.dart:162:30: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
     - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    Try calling using ?. instead.
        WidgetsBinding?.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Failed to package /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit_v3.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/19/zvrhzg415_b51k3jvc_vz1mr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.lzkxYb/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir6KlO8j/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it failed is that your Mac used flutter version 3 which has a change that widget binding cannot be null which required not to use? In Widget binding. The package percentage indicator is not flutter 3 compatible. Please change the version to `percent_indicator: ^4.2.2` which is flutter 3 compatible. Do a flutter clean and pod install and it should work

**Edit**

To clean your pub cache you can run `flutter pub cache clean`

Please note that this will clear all your pub cache which after that you may have to run flutter pub get on all projects

Comment: I use flutter 2.10.5 and percent_indicator: ^4.0.1 just before flutter 3 because all package are not compatible. I have already try clean / pod install / remove pods etc

Comment: In Mac the flutter version looks like it's 3. Can you double check please. And percent indicator  4.2.1 is being used

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have well test 4.2.1, but after error I also test to downgrade to 4.0.1 but always the same problem. Here is my flutter doctor [✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.10.5, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)

Comment: observation -> when I create a new projet with only percent_indicator :4.2.1 loaded it run without error

Comment: run this command in terminal. Switch to a stable channel `flutter channel stable`

Comment: Which definitely means your flutter version is 3. Please check your flutter version in your IDE. If android studio you can check the same in preferences -> language & frameworks -> flutter.. Check the version here too

Comment: In preference it well 2.10.5 channel unknow, unknown source. It’s last version before 3.0.0

Comment: switch channel once and try

Comment: I have try the 3.0 but I have some package who are not compatible 3.0 I can’t remove most of these package to test. i don’t understand why with a blank projet in flutter 2.10.5 percent indicator run, and with my projet it has an error

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check that too

Comment: Ok i will try tonight, 

Comment: :( I try but not working, I have same issue and other

Comment: Since you tried the latest version it might be in your pub cache.  Run flutter pub cache clean. Delete pubspec.lock. Then run flutter pub get and try again

Comment: With percent indicator in pubspec yaml remove the ^ symbol and add the exact version you are trying to use. That should also set the version back to the required one

Comment: I'm lost, I have always more and more errors, It's incomprehensible

Comment: if you change the ^ then again something else is breaking?

Answer (score 0):

Use the follow steps if you use M1 Mac

If you are using Firebase, try to use

```
cloud_firestore: 3.2.1
firebase_analytics: ^9.3.1
firebase_core: 1.19.1
firebase_auth: ^3.6.3
```

Change your Podfile

```
platform :ios, '14.0'
```

**Terminal**

```
flutter clean
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod update
```

Could take a bit time.

**If not work**

Other thing could be .. update your Mac SO, I read some about problems with Monterrey SO, then try to update ,also update Xcode . Good luck